# About SPFolders & DocumentSets

Tags: development, folder, document-set

I've been working in a feature for mi current project that involves folders. I've noticed that If you add files or subfolders to a folder and then you try to update the folder's metadata an exception will be thrown (saying that the the item was modified by [put the userloginname here]), unless you reload the folder (aka fetch it again from the db) before doing the update.

Anyone cares to explain me why this behavior?
Is this documented
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is done to prevent editing of stale data. To get around this you need to request the folder object again after files or sub-folders have been added. This will make sure the metadata changes are done on the latest data. Here are the steps:

1. Retrieve folder object
2. Add files or sub-folders (which made changes to the folder object)
3. **Retrieve folder object again to get the latest version** (not currently being done)
4. Make metadata changes to folder object
5. Update folder

Here is a similar question that may help: [The file * has been modified by SHAREPOINT\system](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46885/the-file-has-been-modified-by-sharepoint-system)